# React native / API Flatlist newly added load data automatically without reloading

Tags: react-native, expo

Im using flatlist for displaying data. each and every time I have to go back and come to same page for displaying newly added data. anyone can you suggest data without refresh the page.

Comment: try to implement pull to refresh so that when data changes , you can explicitly pull to refresh your flatlist

Answer (score 1):

Like this, implement refresh control/ pull to refresh so that you can refresh rather than going back ,

```
<FlatList
        data={this.props.notificationReducer.notifications}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => {
          return this.renderEachCard(item.description, item.added_on, index);
        }}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.props.notificationReducer.pullToRefresh}
            onRefresh={this.getNotificationData}
          />
        }
      />
```

Hope you get it. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thank you Mr.Gaurav Roy but I dont want refresh option. I need like auto load ( Like chat messages no need to refresh)